# jQuery datepicker and selenium

Tags: jquery, python, selenium

I am creating a selenium test and in all the tests I want to simulate the user choosing the date. The problem is when the month changes the possible date selections is limited making it very fragile.

This is my current code:

```
sel.click("fromdate")
sel.click("//div[@id='dp-popup']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]")
sel.click("//div[@id='dp-popup']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]")
```

Is there a way to get around this either creating a function that determines the correct cell to choose or if I should just inject the value into the field ?

Comment: Okay this does not seem to be able to be getting any responses how can I manipulate the dom in selenium like executing a JS command that injects the date value and submits the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using selenium and jQuery date picker. I'm always using [xpath checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) in selenium tests to create stable tests.

Well, this is the path of month name `//html/body/div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/div/span[1]` and this gives the year `//html/body/div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/div/span[2]` and this is `//html/body/div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/table/tbody/tr[**week index of month.you can think this is a row in datepicker**]/td[**column index of a datepicker.you can think this is a day of a week**]`

Try to use xpath checker to get locators. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: These IDs have been improved. ui-datepicker-year, ui-datepicker-month, and ui-datepicker-today.